# What is the impact of Earth's magnetic field polarity on consumer electronics?

Tags: electromagnetism, earth, fault, tolerance

Earth's magnetic poles are known to have inverted in the past. How are commonly used circuits or component of consumer electronics (from energy production/transportation to TVs, mobile phones and PCs) going to be affected?

Other than compasses, I think.

Comment: the effect is generally negligible, no matter the direction of pull. Big old CRTs are the only thing i can think of that are affected, but they would just be slightly distorted in the other direction, not a big deal.

Comment: Very little, you invert the polarity of the magnetic field by rotating your phone, or TV box or computer ect... all the time.  The field stays fixed and rotating would 'simulate' magnetic field reversal, there is no effect. The only thing that might be remotely affected is a CRT monitor, and you may need to adjust it if you move it

Comment: Earth's magnetic field is 25-65 microteslas; it's a worthwhile problem in basic E+M physics to compute what the effect of such a reversal might be, and then a worthwhile electronics engineering problem to conclude what those few milli/micro/nanovolts may or may not do, especially when compared to existing EMI noise.